# Stop casting on the receiver

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I need to disconnect from the sender and return to receiver's main ("ready to cast" screen).
Receiver decides when and how to do that (e.g. 10 mins idling after media playback was paused)

I've tried to stop receiver explicitly

```
receiver.stop()
```

and disconnecting the connection service

```
cs = receiver.getConnectionService()
cs.disconnect()
```

That didn't work as I wanted, it doesn't return to the main screen and all senders still see it as an ongoing cast session

[image]

So how can I force disconnecting on the receiver? [Receiver API page](https://developers.google.com/cast/reference/receiver/jsdoc/) seems to be describing only these two methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't call `receiver.stop()`, nor calling `cs.disconnect();` instead try using `window.close()`.